# ansible: Best Practice for host specific playbooks

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to clean up my ansible infrastructure and wanted to stick to the [best practices](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#content-organization)  as much as possible.

My problem is that I have host-specific tasks that I naturally want to map into the logic as sensibly as possible.

If I want to have both, "best practice" and host-specific tasks, I end up with the following simplified file structure:

```
├── dbservers.yml
├── generic.yml
├── group_templates/
│   └── webservers/
├── group_vars/
│   └── webservers.yml
├── host_files/
│   └── d-ws323/
├── host_tasks/
│   └── d-ws323.yml
├── host_vars/
│   └── d-ws323/
├── production.ini
├── roles/
├── secrets.txt
├── site.yml
└── webservers.yml
```

My approch looks like this:

`site.yml` is the master playbook:

```
---
# file: site.yml
 - import_playbook: webservers.yml
 - import_playbook: dbservers.yml
 - import_playbook: generic.yml
```

And `generic.yml`:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes

  roles:
    - generic
  
  tasks:
  - local_action: stat path=host_tasks/{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml
    register: host_file
    become: no
  - include: host_playbooks/{{ inventory_hostname }}.yml
    when: host_file.stat.exists
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: Aren't you using roles?

Comment: yupp, those are placed under `roles`. I could, of course, put host-specific tasks there with: `when: inventory_hostname == "www1"` but this "feels" more complicated. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I guess I didn't get it. Usually what we do is assign a role (or roles) to a host or group through a playbook. Something like this:

```
--- 
- hosts: my-host
  become: true
  user: stefano
  roles:
    - webservers
    - dbservers
```

Comment: Mhh i updated my question with my current solution...

Comment: Got it! I will post a working solution based on it.

Comment: I really don't get what you are trying to acheive that a classic project layout cannot address already... What is wrong with groups/inventory_hostnames and multiple plays in playbooks targeting the relevant `hosts` pattern ? Can you give an example of those "host specific" tasks that cannot fit in a "normal" ansible layout ?

Comment: Well, lets say i have to configure two LAMP Servers, one for TYPO3 and one with some custom code from a private repo. And lets say that thos tasks are unique to the host. Where should i place those "host-specific" tasks in the best practice way?

Comment: okay got it. I guess i was missunderstanding the use case for roles. in my upper example: the typo3 server is one role and the custom code repo would be another role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we do is create roles that have playbooks and then assign these roles to hosts or groups of hosts. Based on that, we would have a directory layout similar to:

```
.
├── group_vars
├── hosts
├── host_vars
│   └── host-01.yml
├── roles
│   └── webservers
│       ├── files
│       ├── tasks
│       │   └── main.yml
│       └── templates
└── webservers.yml
```

The `hosts` file is the inventory file, which you're gonna put all your hosts and groups, and the `webservers.yml` is the playbook with the following content:

```yaml
--- 
- hosts: host-01
  become: true
  user: ubuntu
  roles:
    - webservers
```

If you have to make any distro-specific arrangement, you should do that inside the role playbook. Playbooks outside roles should exist only for conecting groups or hosts to roles, or very trivial tasks, if possible.

Best regards!

Comment: Mhh so you place the host-specific tasks in one playbook-file, right?

Comment: Yeah, but there are a lot of ways to do it, and Ansible doesn't have a "best practice" for it, really (AFAIK). Some people control host-specifics using conditionals (`when` blocks, like you mentioned - I don't really like that approach because it's hard to maintain it on the long road), others write playbooks with `hosts: all` and then use `--limit` (pretty common with CI/CD implementations), others write specific playbooks just for those hosts...

Comment: By my experience, if there is a rule of thumb, it would be to maximize the use of roles, and make your roles as reusable as possible, and minimize the use of single playbooks as much as you can.